# How to expand the layout after tapping to it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, android-viewpager

I want to zoom in the loaded `layout` of a `viewPager` page `onTouchListner` event. Something like this: [ios app design](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/papercollectionview).

Let me clarify the steps here:

- `ViewPager` gets loaded
- User can see the all pages by swiping right or left
- To get the detail user clicks on a page and it will get zoom in to cover the full screen (`Have a look at the ios app link`)
- User tap on the opened page and it retains it's position again (`second steps`)

How can I achieve this scenario? I tried to search it but couldn't get enough information. Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

If view is a list you can use expendable list

Comment: list? I didn't get it. It can be anything under `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. Anything which can be designed in `viewpager`

Comment: it will work fine   -   https://krishnalalstha.wordpress.com/tag/android-expandable-layout-like-google-play/